# MySQL via SSH + Bash error

Tags: mysql, c, linux, sockets, ssl

ssh root@162.243.67.60 mysql -uroot -p --execute="grant all privileges on wordpress.* to 'firaswp'@'54.89.73.129' identified by 'password'"

it doesn't give me syntax error but instead gives a really weird output. Been trying to get mysql to run the grant privilege option via SSH for 1-2 days now and I still can't figure it out. This isn't the primary line that I want - I actually want to input the IP as a variable inside a script but first, I figure I would get it to work normally.. any help would be appreciated! The output is below.

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
>   readline 5.1 Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]   -?, --help          Display this
>   help and exit.   -I, --help          Synonym for -?   --auto-rehash
>   Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
>                         --disable-auto-rehash.   -A, --no-auto-rehash
>                         No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
>                         table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
>                         mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.   -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
>                         (Enables --silent.)   --character-sets-dir=name
>                         Directory for character set files.   --column-type-info  Display column type information.   -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
>                         default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
>                         with --comments.   -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.   -#, --debug[=#]     This is a
>   non-debug version. Catch this and exit.   --debug-check       Check
>   memory and open file usage at exit.   -T, --debug-info    Print some
>   debug info at exit.   -D, --database=name Database to use.
>   --default-character-set=name
>                         Set the default character set.   --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.   -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
>                         file.)   -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.   -f, --force         Continue even if we
>   get an SQL error.   -G, --named-commands
>                         Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
>                         internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
>                         named commands can be used from any line of the query,
>                         otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
>                         Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
>                         disabled by default.   -g, --no-named-commands
>                         Named commands are disabled. Use * form only, or use
>                         named commands only in the beginning of a line ending
>                         with a semicolon (;). Since version 10.9, the client now
>                         starts with this option ENABLED by default. Disable with
>                         '-G'. Long format commands still work from the first
>                         line. WARNING: option deprecated; use
>                         --disable-named-commands instead.   -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.   --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.   -b, --no-beep       Turn off
>   beep on error.   -h, --host=name     Connect to host.   -H, --html
>   Produce HTML output.   -X, --xml           Produce XML output.
>   --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.   -L, --skip-line-numbers
>                         Don't write line number for errors.   -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.   --column-names      Write column names in results.   -N, --skip-column-names
>                         Don't write column names in results.   -O, --set-variable=name
>                         Change the value of a variable. Please note that this
>                         option is deprecated; you can set variables directly with
>                         --variable-name=value.   --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).   -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except
>   those that occur while the
>                         default database is the one named at the command line.   --pager[=name]      Pager to use to display results. If you
>   don't supply an
>                         option, the default pager is taken from your ENV variable
>                         PAGER. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename],
>                         etc. See interactive help (\h) also. This option does not
>                         work in batch mode. Disable with --disable-pager. This
>                         option is disabled by default.   --no-pager          Disable pager and print to stdout. See interactive help
>                         (\h) also. WARNING: option deprecated; use
>                         --disable-pager instead.   -p, --password[=name]
>                         Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
>                         not given it's asked from the tty.   -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
>                         order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
>                         /etc/services, built-in default (3306).   --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.   --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
>                         memory).   -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
>                         down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
>                         history file.   -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.   --reconnect         Reconnect
>   if the connection is lost. Disable with
>                         --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.   -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a
>   tab as separator,
>                         each row on new line.   -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.   --ssl               Enable SSL
>   for connection (automatically enabled with
>                         other flags).Disable with --skip-ssl.   --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format (check OpenSSL docs, implies
>                         --ssl).   --ssl-capath=name   CA directory (check OpenSSL docs, implies --ssl).   --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert
>   in PEM format (implies --ssl).   --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use
>   (implies --ssl).   --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format (implies
>   --ssl).   --ssl-verify-server-cert
>                         Verify server's "Common Name" in its cert against
>                         hostname used when connecting. This option is disabled by
>                         default.   -t, --table         Output in table format.   --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See
>   interactive help (\h)
>                         also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
>                         --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.   --no-tee            Disable outfile. See interactive help
>   (\h) also. WARNING:
>                         Option deprecated; use --disable-tee instead.   -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.   -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.   -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.   -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).   -V, --version 
>   Output version information and exit.   -w, --wait          Wait and
>   retry if connection is down.   --connect_timeout=# Number of seconds
>   before connection timeout.   --max_allowed_packet=#
>                         The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
>                         server.   --net_buffer_length=#
>                         The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.   --select_limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when
>   using --safe-updates.   --max_join_size=#   Automatic limit for rows
>   in a join when using
>                         --safe-updates.   --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
>                         (pre-4.1.1) protocol.   --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.   --show-warnings     Show
>   warnings after every statement.
>
> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf The following groups are read:
>   mysql client The following options may be given as the first argument:
>   --print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
>   --no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file.
>   --defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
>   --defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
>
> Variables (--variable-name=value) and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE} 
>   Value (after reading options)
>   --------------------------------- ----------------------------- auto-rehash                       TRUE character-sets-dir
>   (No default value) column-type-info                  FALSE comments
>   FALSE compress                          FALSE debug-check
>   FALSE debug-info                        FALSE database
>   (No default value) default-character-set             latin1 delimiter 
>   ; vertical                          FALSE force
>   FALSE named-commands                    FALSE ignore-spaces
>   FALSE local-infile                      FALSE no-beep
>   FALSE host                              (No default value) html
>   FALSE xml                               FALSE line-numbers
>   TRUE unbuffered                        FALSE column-names
>   TRUE sigint-ignore                     FALSE port
>   0 prompt                            mysql> quick
>   FALSE raw                               FALSE reconnect
>   FALSE socket                            (No default value) ssl
>   FALSE ssl-ca                            (No default value) ssl-capath 
>   (No default value) ssl-cert                          (No default
>   value) ssl-cipher                        (No default value) ssl-key
>   (No default value) ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE table
>   FALSE user                              root safe-updates
>   FALSE i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE connect_timeout
>   0 max_allowed_packet                16777216 net_buffer_length
>   16384 select_limit                      1000 max_join_size
>   1000000 secure-auth                       FALSE show-warnings
>   FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your syntax for the mysql command is wrong. I think you need to leave a space between -uroot i.e. -u root
2. Why not break the command down into multiple steps i.e.

   ```
   $ssh root@162.243.67.60
   $mysql -u root -p
   mysql> grant all privileges on wordpress.* to 'firaswp'@'54.89.73.129' identified by 'password'
   ```

Comment: Hey James,

you don't need to leave a space between the -u and username. The reason I want this all to be setup this way is for automation - I don't want to have to log in and type anything.

Comment: ssh root@162.243.67.60 "mysql -u root -p --execute='grant all privileges on wordpress.* to \"firaswp\"@\"54.89.73.129\" identified by \"password\"'" - using a different command/ip this works for me

Comment: Booyah! That was it. I love you, James.